# Ruby - access a function inside modules and a class

Tags: ruby

A basic question - How do I access a function inside a module, then another module, then a class.

In a gem -

```
module Handsoap
  module Http

    # Represents a HTTP Request.
    class Request
      attr_reader :url, :http_method, :headers, :body, :username, :password, :trust_ca_file, :client_cert_file, :client_cert_key_file
      attr_writer :body, :http_method

      def set_trust_ca_file(ca_file)
         @trust_ca_file = ca_file

      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my file, I am trying this -

```
Handsoap:Http::Request.set_trust_ca_file('/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt')

:Http is not a class/module (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Should be

```
Handsoap::Http::Request
```

Also, your method should be class instance method

```
def self.set_trust_ca_file(ca_file)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Oops. fixed that. And now a new error `undefined method 'set_trust_ca_file' for Handsoap::Http::Request:Class (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the checked answer is incorrect.  The set_trust_ca_file() method is not a class method.  It is setting and instance variable, so its an instance method.

You need to call set_trust_ca_file() on an instance of the Request class:

```
var = Handsoap::Http::Request.new
var.set_trust_ca_file(ca_file)
```

You can also eliminate the method altogether because the attr_accessor statement will make the instance variable, @trust_ca_file settable from outside the class:

```
var = Handsoap::Http::Request.new
var.trust_ca_file = "new_value"
```

Comment: It's setting class instance variable, so it's a class instance method. Don't confuse them with instance variable/method. Also it might be more convenient to set `trust_ca_file` once and for all instead of setting it for each new request.